# PHP- da erro mas envia na mesma o que é pedido

Tags: php, sql

Tenho o seguinte código, se não fizer determinado pedido emite um erro, caso não exista esse erro envia email para o usuário. o problema é que para além de aparecer o erro e envia também o email (pf vejam a foto).

```
<?php
 include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST\['submit_email'\]) && isset($_POST\['email'\])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST\['email'\]);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM registo WHERE email = '$email'";
    $r = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($r);
    if($count == 1) {
        // Create new hash
        $key = hash('sha256', uniqid("", true));
        // SQL query to update user record with hash value
        $usql = "UPDATE registo set reset_key = '".$key."' where email = '".$email."'";
        if(!mysqli_query($conn, $usql)) {
            echo "Error updating database!";

        }
        // send link to user with generated key
        $link="<a href='http://unn-w17015779.newnumyspace.co.uk/reset.php?key=".$key."'>Click To Reset password</a>";
        $to = $email;
        $subject = 'Reset Password';
        $message = 'Click On This Link to Reset Password '.$link;
        $headers = 'From: Galaxy books shop <**@gmail.com>' . "\r\n" .
                   'Reply-To: **@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
                   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        // Send email
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo "Your reset link has been sent to your email ";
        }else{
            echo "Failed to Recover your password, try again";
        }
    } else {
        echo "User name does not exist";
    }
}
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O envio do email esta fora do if que verifica o erro na atualização, esse não é um problema do PHP ou SQL mas sim um problema de lógica de programação.

Comment: "se não fizer determinado pedido emite um erro" se referencia a esse trecho do código? echo "Error updating database!";

Comment: Apenas para que esteja ciente o `uniqid()` é baseado em tempo, ele é bom para gerar dados únicos, mas não para gerar dados impressíveis, isto tem diferença. Ele utiliza um gerador extremamente previsível o [LGC, Linear congruential generator,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). O PHP já tem suporte para [CSPRNG](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSPRNG), com o `random_bytes()` ou se quiser confiar em _Userspace CSPRNG_ tem o `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`. Existe inclusive um [RFC para melhorar o uniqid()](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniqid), atualmente fechado.

Answer (score 1):

Se houver código para rodar mesmo que haja erro, pode-se usar uma condição ao invés de exit()

```
       .............
       .............
       if(!mysqli_query($conn, $usql)) {
           echo "Error updating database!";
       }else{
           // send link to user with generated key
           $link="<a href='http://unn-w17015779.newnumyspace.co.uk/reset.php?key=".$key."'>Click To Reset password</a>";
           $to = $email;
           $subject = 'Reset Password';
           $message = 'Click On This Link to Reset Password '.$link;
           $headers = 'From: Galaxy books shop <**@gmail.com>' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: **@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
          // Send email
          if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
              echo "Your reset link has been sent to your email ";
          }else{
              echo "Failed to Recover your password, try again";
          }
      }

    } else {
       echo "User name does not exist";
   }
}
?>

código ..........
código ..........
```

Answer (score 1):

Por garantia adicione o `mysqli_real_escape_string` ao `$key` como fez no `$email`, creio que a hash não contenha `'`, mas pode ser a falha ainda sim:

```
$key = hash('sha256', uniqid("", true));

$keyescaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($key);

$usql = "UPDATE registo set reset_key = '".$keyescaped."' where email = '".$email."'";
```

E na if do `mysqli_query` use o `exit;` para parar o código e também use o `mysqli_error` para descobrir o que falhou assim:

```
if(!mysqli_query($conn, $usql)) {
    echo "Error updating database:", mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}
```

Ou usar `die` assim:

```
mysqli_query($conn, $usql) or die("Error updating database:", mysqli_error($conn);

// send link to user with generated key
$link="<a href='http://unn-w17015779.newnumyspace.co.uk/reset.php?key=".$key."'>Click To Reset password</a>";
```

Outro detalhe com problema na sua pergunta (talvez tenha sido a edição que adicionou isto), são as barras invertidas `\`, realmente isto parece errado

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_email']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
```

Ou você pode simplificar para:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_email'], $_POST['email'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
```

Afinal o [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) pode checar várias variáveis.

Answer (score 0):

Você deveria de utilizar um [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exit.php):

```
    if(!mysqli_query($conn, $usql)) {
        echo "Error updating database!";
        exit();
    }
```

Dessa forma se cair nessa condição será mostrado o erro, devido ao `echo`, e iria encerrar o código, devido ao [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exit.php).